# Keeping distinct combinations (pairs) of observations

Tags: stata

I have a dataset where I have to remove duplicate combinations.

These combinations are pairs of places, one each in two columns:

```
ID    Place1         Place2

1     Ann Arbor      Toledo
2     LA             San Francisco
3     Chicago        Peoria
4     Pittsburgh     Cleveland
5     Richmond       New Port
6     Ann Arbor      Cincinnati
7     LA             San Francisco
8     LA             San Jose
9     Springfield    Chicago
10    Richmond       New Port
11    Atlanta        Greenville
```

How can I get the output below?

```
ID    Place1         Place2

1     Ann Arbor      Toledo
2     LA             San Francisco
3     Chicago        Peoria
4     Pittsburgh     Cleveland
5     Richmond       New Port
6     Ann Arbor      Cincinnati
7     LA             San Jose
8     Springfield    Chicago
9     Atlanta        Greenville
```

Answer (score 1):

The following works for me:

```
clear

input ID  str20 Place1 str20 Place2
1 "Ann Arbor" "Toledo"
2 "LA" "San Francisco"
3 "Chicago" "Peoria"
4 "Pittsburgh" "Cleveland"
5 "Richmond" "New Port"
6 "Ann Arbor" "Cincinnati"
7 "LA" "San Francisco"
8 "LA" "San Jose"
9 "Springfield" "Chicago"
10 "Richmond" "New Port"
11 "Atlanta" "Greenville"
end

duplicates drop Place1 Place2, force

list, separator(0)

     +----------------------------------+
     | ID        Place1          Place2 |
     |----------------------------------|
  1. |  1     Ann Arbor          Toledo |
  2. |  2            LA   San Francisco |
  3. |  3       Chicago          Peoria |
  4. |  4    Pittsburgh       Cleveland |
  5. |  5      Richmond        New Port |
  6. |  6     Ann Arbor      Cincinnati |
  7. |  8            LA        San Jose |
  8. |  9   Springfield         Chicago |
  9. | 11       Atlanta      Greenville |
     +----------------------------------+
```

Type `help duplicates` in Stata's command prompt for details and full syntax.

It is important to note that this will not work if you have pairs in your data like the one below:

```
LA San Francisco 
San Francisco LA
```

See [this](https://journals.sagepub.com/doi/pdf/10.1177/1536867X0800800414) article by @NickCox on how to deal with this case.

Comment: @Nishan my answer clearly solves your problem. Please accept it with the check-mark. This is how you reward volunteers on Stack Overflow for their time and ensure that they will help you again in the future.